# Play Framework 2.2.0 websockets fall back to http streaming

Tags: playframework, websocket, http-streaming, playframework-2.2

I am looking at the chat example that comes with Play Framework 2.2.0. Works great if the client (browser or not) supports websockets. For browsers that do not support websockets, it does not seem to fall back and support HTTP streaming. Does Play Framework 2.2.0 support fallback to streaming when working with websockets?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this mailing list conversation, might be of help: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/play-framework/ocO_fFuZ71Q/discussion